# Generating an Abstract Syntax Tree for java source code using ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

How Can I Generate an AST from java src code Using ANTLR?
any help?

Comment: Way too broad. Start with the ANTLR tutorial, or looking for existing grammars.

Comment: Get a Java grammar. Run Java source through the ANTLR-generated classes. Might be easier to use the Eclipse stuff, though.

Comment: can you please post any useful links or tutorials? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setps to generate java src AST using antlr4 are:

1. Install antlr4 you can use [this](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md) link to do that.
2. After installation download the [JAVA grammar from here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4).
3. Now generate Java8Lexer and Java8Parser using the command:

   `antlr4 -visitor Java8.g4`
4. This will generate several files such as `Java8BaseListener.java`  `Java8BaseVisitor.java`  `Java8Lexer.java`  `Java8Lexer.tokens`  `Java8Listener.java`  `Java8Parser.java`  `Java8.tokens`  `Java8Visitor.java`

Use this code to generate AST:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.RuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

public class ASTGenerator {

    public static String readFile() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("path/to/the/test/file.java");
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        return new String(encoded, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String inputString = readFile();
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(inputString);
        Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(tokens);
        ParserRuleContext ctx = parser.classDeclaration();

        printAST(ctx, false, 0);
    }

    private static void printAST(RuleContext ctx, boolean verbose, int indentation) {
        boolean toBeIgnored = !verbose && ctx.getChildCount() == 1 && ctx.getChild(0) instanceof ParserRuleContext;

        if (!toBeIgnored) {
            String ruleName = Java8Parser.ruleNames[ctx.getRuleIndex()];
            for (int i = 0; i < indentation; i++) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            System.out.println(ruleName + " -> " + ctx.getText());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.getChildCount(); i++) {
            ParseTree element = ctx.getChild(i);
            if (element instanceof RuleContext) {
                printAST((RuleContext) element, verbose, indentation + (toBeIgnored ? 0 : 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After you are done coding you can use gradle to build your project or you can download [antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar](http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar) in your project directory and start compiling.

If you want a the output in a DOT file so that u can visualise the AST then you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435911/generate-ast-in-the-form-of-a-dot-file) QnA post or directly refer to this [repository](https://github.com/satnam-sandhu/ASTGenerator) in which i have used gradle to build the project.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 13):

OK, here are the steps:

1. Go to the [ANTLR site](http://www.antlr.org/) and download the latest version
2. Download the `Java.g` and the `JavaTreeParser.g` files from [here](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1207932239307/Java1_5Grammars).
3. Run the following commands:

   ```
   java -jar antlrTool Java.g
   java -jar antlrTool JavaTreeParser.g
   ```
4. 5 files will be generated:

   1. Java.tokens
   2. JavaLexer.java
   3. JavaParser.java
   4. JavaTreeParser.g
   5. JavaTreeParser.tokens

use this java code to generate the Abstract Syntax Tree and to print it:

```
        String input = "public class HelloWord {"+
                   "public void print(String r){" +
                   "for(int i = 0;true;i+=2)" +
                   "System.out.println(r);" +
                   "}" +
                   "}";

    CharStream cs = new ANTLRStringStream(input);
    JavaLexer jl = new JavaLexer(cs);

    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream();
    tokens.setTokenSource(jl);
    JavaParser jp = new JavaParser(tokens);
    RuleReturnScope result = jp.compilationUnit();
    CommonTree t = (CommonTree) result.getTree();

    CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(t);

    nodes.setTokenStream(tokens);

    JavaTreeParser walker = new JavaTreeParser(nodes);

    System.out.println("\nWalk tree:\n");

    printTree(t,0);


    System.out.println(tokens.toString());

    }

public static void printTree(CommonTree t, int indent) {
    if ( t != null ) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(indent);
        for ( int i = 0; i < indent; i++ )
            sb = sb.append("   ");
        for ( int i = 0; i < t.getChildCount(); i++ ) {
            System.out.println(sb.toString() + t.getChild(i).toString());
            printTree((CommonTree)t.getChild(i), indent+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aboelnour. But the page you are reffering to does not exist anymore. any help?

Comment: Another question, if JavaTreeParser.java is not among generated files, where does it come from?

Comment: @MakanTayebi I think this would help: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4

Comment: @Aboelnour, would you please update this answer for antlr v4?

Comment: sorry guys, my answer is too old, and I don't enough current knowledge for antlr v4...

Comment: If anyone can update the question with a good new answer for v4 I will accept his answer instead of mine.

Comment: the link to the java grammer seems to be broken

Comment: Even if this answer is old, I put the link back: http://www.habelitz.com/images/downloads/javagrammars/Java7WithSomeJava8FeaturesGrammars_2016_01_23.zip