# Generate AST in the form of a dot file

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, antlr3, dot

I am working with ANTLR4 to generate AST of a java source code and i had to move to ANTLR3 because i was not getting much help and documentation and it was really tough to proceed.I managed to generate AST but not in a visual format. Then i came across an awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856612/visualizing-an-ast-created-with-antlr-in-a-net-environment)  and i was really able to generate AST in a DOT file but there was a slight problem.

My code:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRFileStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.CommonTree;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.DOTTreeGenerator;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate;

class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            parseFile("/home/satnam-sandhu/Workstation/ASTGenerator/resource/java/Blabla.java");
        }

    public static void parseFile(String f)throws Exception {

            JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(new ANTLRFileStream(f));
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(tokens);
            CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.compilationUnit().getTree();
            DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
            StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
            System.out.println(st);

    }

}
```

I am using gradle so i build the project by:

```
gradle clean build
```

And then run it and pipe the output to a dot file by:

```
java -jar ASTGenerator.jar > ast.dot
```

Now the issue i am facing is that, for a source code of:

```
class example{
    public static void print(int a){
        int b = a +1;
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static void main(){
        print(15);
    }
}
```

I am getting this as the output:

```
digraph {

    ordering=out;
    ranksep=.4;
    bgcolor="lightgrey"; node [shape=box, fixedsize=false, fontsize=12, fontname="Helvetica-bold", fontcolor="blue"
        width=.25, height=.25, color="black", fillcolor="white", style="filled, solid, bold"];
    edge [arrowsize=.5, color="black", style="bold"]

  n0 [label=""];
  n1 [label="class"];
  n2 [label="example"];
  n3 [label="{"];
  n4 [label="public"];
  n5 [label="static"];
  n6 [label="void"];
  n7 [label="print"];
  n8 [label="("];
  n9 [label="int"];
  n10 [label="a"];
  n11 [label=")"];
  n12 [label="{"];
  n13 [label="int"];
  n14 [label="b"];
  n15 [label="="];
  n16 [label="a"];
  n17 [label="+"];
  n18 [label="1"];
  n19 [label=";"];
  n20 [label="System"];
  n21 [label="."];
  n22 [label="out"];
  n23 [label="."];
  n24 [label="println"];
  n25 [label="("];
  n26 [label="b"];
  n27 [label=")"];
  n28 [label=";"];
  n29 [label="}"];
  n30 [label="public"];
  n31 [label="static"];
  n32 [label="void"];
  n33 [label="main"];
  n34 [label="("];
  n35 [label=")"];
  n36 [label="{"];
  n37 [label="print"];
  n38 [label="("];
  n39 [label="15"];
  n40 [label=")"];
  n41 [label=";"];
  n42 [label="}"];
  n43 [label="}"];

  n0 -> n1 // "" -> "class"
  n0 -> n2 // "" -> "example"
  n0 -> n3 // "" -> "{"
  n0 -> n4 // "" -> "public"
  n0 -> n5 // "" -> "static"
  n0 -> n6 // "" -> "void"
  n0 -> n7 // "" -> "print"
  n0 -> n8 // "" -> "("
  n0 -> n9 // "" -> "int"
  n0 -> n10 // "" -> "a"
  n0 -> n11 // "" -> ")"
  n0 -> n12 // "" -> "{"
  n0 -> n13 // "" -> "int"
  n0 -> n14 // "" -> "b"
  n0 -> n15 // "" -> "="
  n0 -> n16 // "" -> "a"
  n0 -> n17 // "" -> "+"
  n0 -> n18 // "" -> "1"
  n0 -> n19 // "" -> ";"
  n0 -> n20 // "" -> "System"
  n0 -> n21 // "" -> "."
  n0 -> n22 // "" -> "out"
  n0 -> n23 // "" -> "."
  n0 -> n24 // "" -> "println"
  n0 -> n25 // "" -> "("
  n0 -> n26 // "" -> "b"
  n0 -> n27 // "" -> ")"
  n0 -> n28 // "" -> ";"
  n0 -> n29 // "" -> "}"
  n0 -> n30 // "" -> "public"
  n0 -> n31 // "" -> "static"
  n0 -> n32 // "" -> "void"
  n0 -> n33 // "" -> "main"
  n0 -> n34 // "" -> "("
  n0 -> n35 // "" -> ")"
  n0 -> n36 // "" -> "{"
  n0 -> n37 // "" -> "print"
  n0 -> n38 // "" -> "("
  n0 -> n39 // "" -> "15"
  n0 -> n40 // "" -> ")"
  n0 -> n41 // "" -> ";"
  n0 -> n42 // "" -> "}"
  n0 -> n43 // "" -> "}"

}
```

When using http://viz-js.com/ for visualising the output is like this:
[image]

All my work till now is uploaded [here](https://github.com/satnam-sandhu/ASTGenerator/tree/antlr3hopes) if you guys feel like to dig deeper into the grammar file i am using. I think options specified in the grammar file can also be the reason.
I am a beginner cannot proceed without a little help. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You need to mark root nodes in the `Java.g` file as shown in this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931346/how-to-output-the-ast-built-using-antlr

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks @Bart Kiers. But i am using the grammar available in antlr's official repository so is there a  way to get a Java grammar with already marked nodes?

Comment: Not that I know of. You'll have to add them to the grammar yourself. You're welcome, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer i was looking for is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931346/how-to-output-the-ast-built-using-antlr) by [Bart Kiers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50476/bart-kiers) but for people who want to generate DOT files without modifying the grammar can print a intended syntax tree by taking help from this [repository](https://github.com/ftomassetti/python-ast).
Since i did not find much documentation on dot generation in ANTLR4 and no other option other than to modify ANTLR3 grammar file, i used [Federico Tomassetti](https://github.com/ftomassetti) example and modified it a little to generate our own DOT file.

You can print a Dot file output by:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.RuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

public class ASTGenerator {

    static ArrayList<String> LineNum = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> Type = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> Content = new ArrayList<String>();

    private static String readFile() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("resource/java/Blabla.java");
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        return new String(encoded, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        String inputString = readFile();
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(inputString);
        Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(tokens);
        ParserRuleContext ctx = parser.compilationUnit();

        generateAST(ctx, false, 0);

    System.out.println("digraph G {");
        printDOT();
    System.out.println("}");

    }

    private static void generateAST(RuleContext ctx, boolean verbose, int indentation) {
        boolean toBeIgnored = !verbose && ctx.getChildCount() == 1 && ctx.getChild(0) instanceof ParserRuleContext;

        if (!toBeIgnored) {
            String ruleName = Java8Parser.ruleNames[ctx.getRuleIndex()];
        LineNum.add(Integer.toString(indentation));
            Type.add(ruleName);
            Content.add(ctx.getText());
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.getChildCount(); i++) {
            ParseTree element = ctx.getChild(i);
            if (element instanceof RuleContext) {
                generateAST((RuleContext) element, verbose, indentation + (toBeIgnored ? 0 : 1));
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static void printDOT(){
        printLabel();
        int pos = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<LineNum.size();i++){
            pos=getPos(Integer.parseInt(LineNum.get(i))-1, i);
            System.out.println((Integer.parseInt(LineNum.get(i))-1)+Integer.toString(pos)+"->"+LineNum.get(i)+i);
        }
    }
    
    private static void printLabel(){
        for(int i =0; i<LineNum.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(LineNum.get(i)+i+"[label=\""+Type.get(i)+"\\n "+Content.get(i)+" \"]");
        }
    }
    
    private static int getPos(int n, int limit){
        int pos = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<limit;i++){
            if(Integer.parseInt(LineNum.get(i))==n){
                pos = i;
            }
        }
        return pos;
    }
}
```

For a source code like this:

```
class example{
  public static void main(){
    int a;
    a = 5;
  }
}
```

Output will be:

```
digraph G {
00[label="compilationUnit\n classexample{publicstaticvoidmain(){inta;a=5;}}<EOF> "]
11[label="normalClassDeclaration\n classexample{publicstaticvoidmain(){inta;a=5;}} "]
22[label="classBody\n {publicstaticvoidmain(){inta;a=5;}} "]
33[label="methodDeclaration\n publicstaticvoidmain(){inta;a=5;} "]
44[label="methodModifier\n public "]
45[label="methodModifier\n static "]
46[label="methodHeader\n voidmain() "]
57[label="result\n void "]
58[label="methodDeclarator\n main() "]
49[label="block\n {inta;a=5;} "]
510[label="blockStatements\n inta;a=5; "]
611[label="localVariableDeclarationStatement\n inta; "]
712[label="localVariableDeclaration\n inta "]
813[label="integralType\n int "]
814[label="variableDeclaratorId\n a "]
615[label="expressionStatement\n a=5; "]
716[label="assignment\n a=5 "]
817[label="expressionName\n a "]
818[label="assignmentOperator\n = "]
819[label="literal\n 5 "]
00->11
11->22
22->33
33->44
33->45
33->46
46->57
46->58
33->49
49->510
510->611
611->712
712->813
712->814
510->615
615->716
716->817
716->818
716->819
}
```

Insert this piece of output in http://viz-js.com/
You will get this as ouput:
[image]

You can also pipe the output to ast.dot file by:

```
java -jar path-to-jar-file.jar > ast.dot
```

Now this is not the perfect method but enough for me. :)

Hope this helps.